# Elasticsearch and Python: get total variable

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I use the python API of ES in order send request, I try to get the result of my answer, but it's wrong.
I use this code:

```
   import elasticsearch

   es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(["127.0.0.1:9200"])
   results = es.search(index="bhinneka", body={"query": {"match": {"name": '"'+reference+'"'}}})

   if results['hits']:
       print('-' * 80)
       print results['hits']['total']

   for hit in results['hits']['hits']:
       print hit['_source']['name']
```

In fact, when i verify the result from my web browser, i've got -for example- the total variable at 5, with my code i've got the total at 42 -for example-.

if someone has an answer to this mystery, I'm interested :)

thanks in advance

Comment: How do you verify the result from your web browser? Perhaps you use some plugin that gives back 5 results at a time?

Answer (score 0):

I use this query:

```
127.0.0.1:9200/bhinneka/bhinneka/_search?q=name:%22reference%22&pretty=true
```

And I've got this result:

```
{
  ...
  "hits": {
    "total": 5,
    "max_score": 9.990799,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "bhinneka",
        "_type": "bhinneka",
        "_id": "ySosUTHKSESxo7ScOOhUZw",
        "_score": 9.990799,
        "_source": {
          ...
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your web query, you specify both type and index `bhinneka`, while in Python, you only set the index. Could that be an issue? Try to do the web query without specifying the type.